# ¿Como validar texto obtenido al leer un codigo qr con una String?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qrcode

Estoy intentando validar el texto obtenido mediante un escaneo de codigo Qr y compararlo con un String pero no me funciona; Estoy Usando Barcode y Android Studio.

Si tambien me pudieran decir como compararlo con un String en este caso se llama prueba.

Les dejo mi codigo:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ReaderQrCodes extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_SERVICE = 1;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    TextView textView;
    String prueba ="";
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader_qr_codes);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewShow);
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480).build();

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReaderQrCodes.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            ReaderQrCodes.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            CAMERA_SERVICE);
                }try{
                    cameraSource.start(holder);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes= detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (qrCodes.size() !=0){

                    if(qrCodes.toString().contentEquals("TextodePrueba")){
                        Toast.makeText(ReaderQrCodes.this, "Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

En si no quiero Mostrar un Toas si no que inicie un Metodo que aun no he creado, pero en si es todo.

Gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno. Texto de relleno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas realizando la comparación de forma incorrecta, `qrCodes` es un `SparseArray` de objetos `Barcode` por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
 if(qrCodes.toString().contentEquals("TextodePrueba")){
```

la comparación debe realizarse  de esta forma, por ejemplo si deseas comparar el primer elemento del `SparseArray` ( `qrcode.valueAt(0).displayValue` ) :

```
   if(qrcode.valueAt(0).displayValue.contentEquals("TextodePrueba")){
```